# MongoDB findOne() cant find _id by Params

Tags: mongodb, find

Its a really simple example and I am sorry if I was to blind to find the correct answer.
I want to find the correct document by the mongo _id property. The ID is provided by params in the request URL like: `api/endpoint/d4r8f73948f39`

API looks like this:

```
router.get('api/endpoint/:id')
```

I can extract the string by `const id = ctx.params.id` (I am using koa, but that shouldnt bother me)
now doing `db.collection('XXX').findOne({ _id: id })`

This return null even thought I insert the same ID as a string. Using `ObjectID(id)` doesn't help either because `findOne` expects a string. Hardcoding the string doesn't work. Using an Object with the string inside doensn't work. If I query for the document and use their `_id` prop it works, so my function is correct.

I think this is a typical use-case and I don't know why nobody seems to have the same issue as I do.

Comment: Can you post `db.collection('XXX').findOne({ })` ? We can see what is your `_id` looks like

Answer (score 0):

After all it turned out that MongoDB generates a ObjectID() and someone else was saving a string in the database as uuid somewhere. Sorry for the trouble.